# (Swift) How to manage names of tableView cells after expanding tableViewSection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, expandable

In one of sections, when I click toggleSwitch it should expand with number of the same cells depending on `array.count`

Method below works fine. When I click toggle it expands a section with number of rows equal number of elements in array:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return 7
        case 4:
            if expand == true {
                return array.count + 1
            }
            else {
                return 1
            }
        default:
            return 1
        }
    }
```

`array` can have any number of elements, depending on data in Realm. So it can be 0, but it can also be 5, 14 etc. 
Code in `CellForRowAt` also works fine, expands the section with animation:

```
 cell.labelCell.text = "elements (\(array.count))"

 cell.cellSwitch.isOn = self.expand

 cell.callback = { [unowned self] check in
      self.expand = check
      UIView.transition(with: tableView,
                          duration: 0.5,
                          options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                          animations: { self.tableView.reloadData()})
                }
```

**NOTE :** All new cells in section are the same type as their parent cell. So each of new cells has got its own name, switch... 
**Question :** How can I make new cells have their names like the elements in `array`. Like: if the first element in array is `"abc"` , I want to make first cell's : cell.labelCell.text = "abc" (array[0])

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Swift) How to hide some sections in tableView when toggle switch is on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60414472/swift-how-to-hide-some-sections-in-tableview-when-toggle-switch-is-on)

Comment: Question is not the same. It would be very unclear if I put all this code and these questions in the past question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
cell.labelCell.text = "elements (\(array.count))"
```

with

```
cell.labelCell.text = "elements (\(array[indexPath.row]))"
```

Side note:

You could get the animation for free if you reload only the section rather than the entire table view.

Comment: Nice. I have just only changed it to `"elements (\(array[indexPath.row-1]))"` to avoid `index out of range`